# LIKE / OR SQL Query, syntax error or faulty logic?

Tags: sql, search, logic, syntax-error, search-engine

I am making a member search engine where there is a text field and three sql columns called interest_1, interest_2, and interest_3 . Let's say that one of the members have their columns occupied with different words interest_1 = cat, interest_2 = dog, and interest_3 = fish. I want the search engine to allow users to type in (for example) cat into the text field, click on the search button, and it would check for and show results for those who have the word cat in either interest_1, interest_2, or interest_3 (which means that one person can have interest_1 = cat and another have interest_3 = cat and they all appear in the search result).

Therefore I tried to make this query:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM search_table WHERE
something LIKE '{$something}%'
&& (interest LIKE '{$interest_1}%' OR interest LIKE '{$interest_2}%' OR interest LIKE                    '{$interest_3}%')
&& (interest_2 LIKE '{$interest_1}%' OR interest_2 LIKE '{$interest_2}%' OR interest_2 LIKE '{$interest_3}%')
&& (interest_3 LIKE '{$interest_1}%' OR interest_3 LIKE '{$interest_2}%' OR interest_3 LIKE '{$interest_3}%')
&& something LIKE '{$something}%'
;");
```

What happens is that when people search for something else with other textboxes and leave the interest field blank, the search engine successfully filters the results. However if one tried to typed in and search through the interest textfield, every single member in the database shows up (nothing gets filtered).

I checked over it and the query seemed logical to me so I suspect it's a syntax error. However I could be wrong and the syntax is correct, but my logic on this one is faulty. Can anyone tell me what the problem is and how do I repair this query?

Comment: In over 90% of the cases where a query string is being formed and there is an error, you can spot the error very easily by looking at the resulting query.  Assign the string to a variable and print it out to see what is actually being run.  Edit your question with the result if it is not obvious.

Comment: imho the problem is not with your query, but with your table design; you should not have interest as a repeating group, but rather have a separate association table with a foreign key to your main table and a single interest column - then your query would be much simpler (and I doubt much slower, if not faster)

Answer (score 0):

When `{$something}` is empty, the query will return all records. So check if it is empty first. If not, filter using `LIKE`.

Use this logic for every condition in `WHERE` clause:

```
({$something}='' OR something LIKE '{$something}%')
```

**OR**

```
({$something} IS NULL OR something LIKE '{$something}%')
```

**Explanation:**

If this condition is added in your `WHERE` clause, it will filter the records with `LIKE` only if `{$something}` is **not** empty or null.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the logic that you want is `or` not `and` for the three interests:

```
where something LIKE '{$something}%' and
      (interest LIKE '{$interest_1}%' OR interest LIKE '{$interest_2}%' OR interest LIKE                    '{$interest_3}%') or
       interest_2 LIKE '{$interest_1}%' OR interest_2 LIKE '{$interest_2}%' OR interest_2 LIKE '{$interest_3}%' or
       interest_3 LIKE '{$interest_1}%' OR interest_3 LIKE '{$interest_2}%' OR interest_3 LIKE '{$interest_3}%'
      ) and
      something LIKE '{$something}%';
```

It is unlikely that three columns called `interest`, `interest_2`, and `interest_3` would *all* start with the same interest value.  And, for people who read SQL, `AND` is much preferred over `&&`. (Although MySQL does support both, `AND` is ANSI standard and used by all databases.)

And, while mentioning the columns, having the same entity ("interest") repeated in multiple columns is usually a sign of poor database design.  You should probably have a junction/association table, with one row per whatever and interest.